# What does this Android error log mean?

Tags: android

User of my Android app says that it's crashing, without the force close dialog - the Activity just disappears and homescreen is shown. He sent this error log, what does it mean?

```
I/DEBUG   ( 1337): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   ( 1337): Build fingerprint: 'verizon/inc/inc/inc:2.1-update1/ERE27/161494:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   ( 1337): pid: 13046, tid: 13059  >>> cz.fhejl.pubtran <<<
I/DEBUG   ( 1337): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 0000000b
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):  r0 00000003  r1 000000ab  r2 00000008  r3 00000002
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):  r4 46d29d3e  r5 43057f08  r6 4730cca8  r7 00000846
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):  r8 ad0100c0  r9 00000008  10 45052698  fp 003722a0
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):  ip 00000046  sp 4730cc68  lr ad014bb8  pc ad01125c  cpsr 20000010
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):          #00  pc 0001125c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):          #01  pc 0001ac10  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):          #02  pc 0001a0c4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):          #03  pc 00050fe0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):          #04  pc 00051012  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):          #05  pc 00045598  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):          #06  pc 00010010  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):          #07  pc 0000fae4  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1337): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1337): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   ( 1337): ad01124c e7950102 e7951103 e3500000 0a000f66 
I/DEBUG   ( 1337): ad01125c e5903008 e0800101 e1510003 2a000f49 
I/DEBUG   ( 1337): ad01126c e1f470b4 e5902010 e207c0ff e7852109 
I/DEBUG   ( 1337): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1337): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   ( 1337): ad014ba8 112fff10 ea000003 e1a00004 fa01340e 
I/DEBUG   ( 1337): ad014bb8 e3500000 112fff10 e5054008 e24f800c 
I/DEBUG   ( 1337): ad014bc8 e2488c4b e1d470b0 e5960038 e3500000 
I/DEBUG   ( 1337): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1337): stack:
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc28  000003a0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc2c  4513aca8  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc30  00000018  
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc34  ad01859c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc38  40036740  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/zygote/0 (deleted)
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc3c  43057f08  
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc40  ad08b368  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc44  00000322  
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc48  ad0100c0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc4c  46d29c32  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@cz.fhejl.pubtran.apk@classes.dex
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc50  45052698  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc54  ad046099  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc58  46d29c32  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@cz.fhejl.pubtran.apk@classes.dex
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc5c  46d29d38  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@cz.fhejl.pubtran.apk@classes.dex
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc60  df002777  
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc64  e3a070ad  
I/DEBUG   ( 1337): #00 4730cc68  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc6c  4730cca8  
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc70  00015fc8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc74  ad01aba8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc78  43057fe4  
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc7c  ad08ddc8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc80  4730ced8  
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc84  429ee550  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc88  003722a0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc8c  ad01ac14  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1337): #01 4730cc90  003722a0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc94  4730cca8  
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc98  ad01aba8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1337):     4730cc9c  ad01a0c8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
```

This is log output, after the moment it crashes. My app doesn't use NDK, it uses Android Library Project and I'm loading some classes via Class.forName(...).

Comment: Is you app outputting all errors through "INFO"? Is there anything on the ERROR log?

Answer (score 0):

It's crashing inside the Dalvik VM.  I'm not able to decode the stack trace (private verizon build).  A fault address of 0000000b doesn't sound like a null pointer dereference... maybe a data structure inside the VM got corrupted?

Has this been run on a variety of devices and only this one has a problem?  Do you know if other people with the same device have this issue?  I'm wondering if something got corrupted, and uninstall/reinstall of your app would help.

Comment: I got only one report like this, reinstall didn't help.